# Javascript Module inheritence

Tags: javascript

Parent Module,

```
var Component = function () {
    var _componentName;
    var _test = 'ts';
    return {
        getName: function(){
            console.log('getName() is called');
            console.log(this._componentName);
            console.log(_test);
            return _componentName;
        }
    };
};

module.exports = Component;
```

Child module,

```
var Component = require('./component');

var Skip_button = function () {
    var skipBtn = Component();
    skipBtn._componentName = 'Skip_Btn';
    return skipBtn;
};

module.exports = Skip_button;
```

In another place, when I call

```
var skipBtn = Skip_button();
skipBtn.getName();
```

if it is `console.log(this._componentName);` in Component, the value can be printed out successfully. However, if it is `console.log(_componentName);`, undefine error will be there. Any idea?

**[Update]**
Check this out. It works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/nedvedyy/Lvxqjo9v/1 so the question is still, why it does not work in my original code example above if `console.log(this._componentName);` is changed to `console.log(_componentName);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Component` funtion `_componentName` and `_test` are not in the `this` scope. but however you are setting `skipBtn._componentName` in the `Skip_button` function means you are setting `_componentName` in the `this` scope.
thats why `console.log(this._componentName)` printing 'Skip_Btn'

```js
var Component = function () {
    var _componentName;
    var _test = 'ts';
    return {
        getName: function(){
            console.log('getName() is called');
            console.log(this._componentName);
            console.log(this._test);
            return _componentName;
        }
    };
};

var Skip_button = function () {
    var skipBtn = Component();
    skipBtn._componentName = 'Skip_Btn';
    return skipBtn ;
};

var skipBtn = Skip_button();
skipBtn.getName();
```

If you run the above script `this._test` will print 'undefined' becuase `_test` is not in the `this` scope.

```js
var Component = function () {
        var _componentName = 'test';
        var _test = 'ts';
        return {
            getName: function(){
                console.log('getName() is called');
                console.log(_componentName);
                console.log(_test);
                return _componentName;
            }
        };
    };

    var Skip_button = function () {
        var skipBtn = Component();
        skipBtn._componentName = 'Skip_Btn';
        return skipBtn ;
    };

    var skipBtn = Skip_button();
    skipBtn.getName();
```

If you run the above code, `console.log(_componentName)` will print 'test' becasue it has some value

Comment: yes, i think this is the right answer. for console.log(_componentName); , it will retrieve the _componentName in Component as it is a closure. The print out of 'undefine' is _componentName has not been given any value in Component. So http://jsfiddle.net/nedvedyy/Lvxqjo9v/1 explains the cause.

Answer (score 1):

> However, if it is console.log(_componentName);, undefine error will be
>   there

This is because when you do  `return Skip_button;` inside an anonymous method and if `Skip_button` is not in global context then it will return `undefined`.

If you simply want to be able to inherit from a method `Skip_button` and want to be able to invoke `getName` then simply replace

```
return Skip_button;
```

with

```
return skipBtn ;
```

**DEMO**

```js
var Component = function () {
    var _componentName;
    var _test = 'ts';
    return {
        getName: function(){
            console.log('getName() is called');
            console.log(this._componentName);
            console.log(_test);
            return _componentName;
        }
    };
};

var Skip_button = function () {
    var skipBtn = Component();
    skipBtn._componentName = 'Skip_Btn';
    return skipBtn ;
};

var skipBtn = Skip_button();
skipBtn.getName();
```

Comment: Sorry, I update my question. A typo there. Actually I am returning skipBtn

Comment: @Hammer In that case your code should work, check the demo.

Comment: Yes. Actually my question was if remove "this" in console.log(this._componentName), why it wont work.

Comment: @Hammer since `_componentName` updated by `Skip_Button` is not in current or parent scope. So the variable `_componentName` in parent scope always remain undefined.

Comment: Check this out. It works as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/nedvedyy/Lvxqjo9v/1/   so the question is till, why it does not work in my code example above without "this."

Comment: @Hammer It doesn't work for your example because `_componentName` that was set in `Skip_button` doesn't have the global scope. So, `_componentName`  declared inside Component is not visible to Skip_Button.

Comment: Can take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/nedvedyy/Lvxqjo9v/1/  ? it will be clearer

Comment: @Hammer I have seen it, but what is the point you are trying to make?

Comment: for "@Hammer since _componentName updated by Skip_Button is not in current or parent scope. So the variable _componentName in parent scope always remain undefined." Pls try https://jsfiddle.net/nedvedyy/Lvxqjo9v/1/, you will see the child(skip_btn) have access to parent's attr

Comment: @Hammer It is not parent's attribute, it is child's attribute only. First of all, unless you do `var child = new Parent()` there is no inheritance. You are simply using the value returned by a function. Try removing `child.attr = 'childAttr';` in both example and see the output.

Comment: I removed. pls take a look https://jsfiddle.net/nedvedyy/Lvxqjo9v/3/ , Maybe inheritance is a confusing term here. But child does have the access to Parent's  _componentName, as it forms a closure in Parent

Comment: @Hammer check this update https://jsfiddle.net/Lvxqjo9v/4/, now why does it returned undefined for last one?

Comment: yes, it is because of  'this' in getAttr : function(){alert(this.attr);} ; here 'this' is the instance of Child, which does not attr

Comment: @Hammer Precisely the situation with your code, isn't it? Now read my second comment again (4th one of the post).

Comment: yes, you are right. I think the confusion comes from "inheritance" in my question. My bad.  Thanks again.